# Uncomfortable difference between machine libraries and SDK libraries

Tags: qt-creator, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have this situation:

- I'm working on a device with my yocto (pyro) distribution. The device works properly.
- Sdk generated with

  > bitbake -c populate_sdk myimagename-sdk
- Qt Creator kit added like in the instructions: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Using Qt Creator (when debugging and running) it warn me about the absence of some libraries.

> Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
>   GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
>   and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.Could not load shared library symbols for 22 libraries, e.g. /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.
>   Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
>   Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

I temporarily solved the problem by copying the libraries located on the device in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` into a folder called `sysroot` and set the qtcreator debugger by adding : `set sysroot /home/user/sdkroot/sysroot`.

To avoid my temporary solution **it is possible, when compiling sdk, to include all the libraries (including those that go to the device)?**

I searched for settings for the `local.conf` or `*.bb includes` without finding anything useful.

Thanks in advance and *excuse my English*

---

### EDIT

I tried to "use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing" (as suggested by qtcreator), for a very simple program, following these steps:

#### device side

- `gdbserver --multi :1000`

#### pc side

- `./arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gdb`  #to start the gdb of my toolchain
- `target extended-remote 192.168.77.1:10000`
- `run /tmp/myapp`  #previously deployed by qtcreator
- `file ~/sdk/example/build-myapp-kit_device-Debug/myapp`   #load symbol table
- `break 44`  #breakpoint at line 44
- `run`
- `info sharedlibrary`

This is the list I get:

> /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5; /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6; /lib/libgcc_s.so.1;
>   /lib/libc.so.6; /lib/libthread.so.0; /lib/libz.so.1;
>   /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.53; /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.53; /lib/librt.so.1;
>   /lib/libm.so.6; /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

These are libraries that are already in the sysroot of my toochain (which I linked in "sysroot" in the qtcreator kit). And by doing a binary comparison, the result is that they are identical to the libraries I picked up from the device and that I added in qtcreator (as mentioned above: `set sysroot /home/user/sdkroot/sysroot`)

**If the libraries my apps are requesting are already in the toolchain's sysroot, why do I still have to add them from the device?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `bitbake -c populate_sdk myimagename-sdk`

you should use `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5`
This will include all the qt5-dev and qt5-mkspec as well as others path configuration into your toolchain;

You could also copy and paste the stuff in the meta-toolchain-qt5 recipe to your sdk.

recipe is here:
https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb

Answer (score 0):

Building an image based SDK should give you all the libries in the actual image.

In the case of Qt5, your image should incluce:

```
inherit populate_sdk_qt5
```

That should ensure that you get Qt5 in your SDK, when you run `bitbake -c populate_sdk myimagename`. Note, you should be able to use your normal image here.

Also worth noting, that there are a regression currently in Pyro, which causes some libraries header files to be missing from the SDK (this doesn't apply to Qt5, though).

Comment: "inherit populate_sdk_qt5" is already in my .bb file and do not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You can find information [here](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux) on setting up Qtcreator to cross compile for Embedded Linux. Two three things are specific to the concerned company link but otherwise pretty generic.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. These are the steps I have used; are the same settings as in point 3 of my question.
It do not solve my problem :(